# How to .Update() the Update panel from another Form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have searched and done all my research but I can't seem to find the answer that I need.

I need my Update panel on Page1.aspx to change/update when I click on the submit button on Page2.aspx...

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: How is the relation between the aspx pages? Will they be open in two different windows?

Comment: Tim, I have no idea what is iFrames...

Comment: K-B, yes the one window will be open. For instance I click on a button on my Parent page to open new window... and then after I click on the button on the Child window, I want the UpdatePanel from the Parent to update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.opener.__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');" />
```